# How to fill a user control?

Tags: winforms, user-controls, c#-2.0

How can I stretch a user control?

I have a userControl it's highlighted in blue. Is's a TabControl.

How do I strech it to fill the entire parent.

[image]

And how to make ComboBox stretched if GroupBox changes[image]

**Update**
Please provide the code with this structure:
- Window -> panel -> MyuserContorl
- MyUserControl -> panel -> tabControl

To all stretched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can anchor your user control by setting the `Anchor`.

Here's a useful [article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908)

Edit:

In your `user control`

```
     this.tabControl.Anchor = ((AnchorStyles)((((AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom)
         | AnchorStyles.Left) | AnchorStyles.Right)));
```

You may also need to `Dock` or `Anchor` the panel inside your `user control`.

In your window

```
     this.userControl.Anchor = ((AnchorStyles)((((AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom)
         | AnchorStyles.Left) | AnchorStyles.Right)));
```

Again you may need to `Dock` or `Anchor` the panel inside your form.

Comment: If I remove Size in TabControl or Parent panel UserControl become very small.

Comment: what to do with the size of the properties ?

Comment: @simply you'll have to give initial sizes. controls will automatically stretch when the window is resized.